# meaning of 詰めの甘さ

Tags: translation, meaning

I wonder, what term　詰めの甘さ　could mean?
The whole sentense is: 三種の器に入れてもらえなかった詰めの甘さなのだろうか

Comment: Have you looked up 詰めが甘い?

Comment: Yes, i found only "slack". So, it turns out that 詰めの甘さ　means "weakness". But it doesn't make too much sense...

Answer (score 6):

「[詰]{つ}め」 originally means "checkmating" in Japanese board games.  From that, we often use the word to refer to the "final stage" or "final move" in all kinds of things.

「[甘]{あま}い」 here does not mean "sweet".  It means "not severe", "permissive", etc.  If you were being permissive or lenient at the final stage of a game of chess or something, you would not be likely to win.

「詰めの甘さ」, therefore, means "one's tendency to slack off at the end of something".